# Prove that $1 · 1! + 2 · 2! + … + n · n! = (n + 1)! − 1$ via mathematical induction?

Tags: induction, factorial

I have gotten all the way to $(k+1)!-1 +(k+1)(k+1)! = (k+2)-1$. I do not know how to proceed from here. I have seen this question in the forum before, but it did not fully explain the process. I also did not want to revive an old question (not sure if it's against the rules).

How do you go from $(k+1)! - 1 + (k+1)(k+1)!$ to $(k+1)!(1+(k+1))−1$? This has me stumped.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Hi! I've done the first two steps, that is proving P(n) is true for n=1, and assuming that P(k) is true for n=k.

So far I am trying to prove that P(k+1) is true for n=k+1.
P(k)+(k+1)(k+1)!=((k+1)+1)-1
P(k)=(k+1)!-1, plug into equation
(k+1)!-1 + (k+1)(k+1)! = ((k+1)+1)! -1

Simplify right hand side yields
(k+1)!-1 + (k+1)(k+1)! = (k+2)!-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n = 1\cdot1!+2\cdot2!+...+n\cdot n!$ and $b_n = (n+1)!-1$. Then, for $n=1$, we have $a_1 = 1 = b_1$ so the argument holds. Now, suppose inductively that $n \ge 2$ and $a_n = b_n$ for all $n$. Then, for $n+1$, we have
$$a_{n+1} = 1\cdot1!+2\cdot2!+...+n\cdot n!+(n+1)\cdot (n+1)! = a_n+(n+1)\cdot (n+1)!$$
by inductive assumption and which is also
$$ a_{n+1} = a_n+(n+1)\cdot (n+1)! = (n+1)!-1+(n+1)\cdot (n+1)!$$
$$ = (n+1)!(n+1+1)-1$$
$$ = (n+2)!-1$$
$$ = b_{n+1}$$
since inductive assumption claims that $a_n = b_n = (n+1)!-1$.

So we have $a_{n+1} = b_{n+1}$. Therefore by induction, argument holds for all $n$.

Comment: Thank you AresnBerk! 

I'm still a little bit lost. How did you get from (n+1)! - 1 + (n+1) * (n+1)! to (n+1)!(n+1+1)-1?

Comment: The term $(n+1)!$ is mutual so if we sum $(n+1)\cdot (n+1)!$ and $1\cdot (n+1)!$, we get $(n+1+1)(n+1)! = (n+2)(n+1)!$, which is equal to $(n+2)!$. Consider it as the summation $(n+1)\cdot a+a$ where $a = (n+1)!$.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with factorials... could you please explain it thoroughly? 

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: So, did you get why $(n+1)!+(n+1)(n+1)!=(n+1+1)(n+1)! = (n+2)(n+1)!$?

Comment: I got how (n+1+1)(n+1)! = (n+2)(n+1)!, but I do not get how (n+1) * a + a = (n+1+1)(a) where a=(n+1).

Comment: Okay, then could you tell me how can we express the summation $a+b\cdot a$? Here, $a$ and $b$ are just arbitrary numbers, forget about the question you asked for now.

Comment: a(1+b) is how I would express it differently...

Comment: Yes, it is exactly $a(1+b)$. Now, put $(n+1)!$ instead of $a$ and put $(n+1)$ instead of $b$, then what do you get (that's why I said $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary numbers, so you can put whatever expression you want in their place)?

Comment: EDIT: (n+1)!(1+(n+1).

Comment: Oh I see, then it becomes (n+2)(n+1)! which is (n+2)!. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Yes, you got it. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=1}^nkk!=\sum_{k=1}^n(k+1-1)k!=\sum_{k=1}^n((k+1)!-k!)=(n+1)!-1.$$